# Apache Tika: exctract file names and MIME types from archive

Tags: java, parsing, apache-tika

I want Tika to output only the fileName and MIME type of the files.
I found some solution with **RecursiveParserWrapperHandler** but the problem is **BodyContentHandler** always try to parse whole file and put text to body content as result. In my case I need only Map(fileName, MIMEType) as return result, without parsing whole file.
How can i do that?

```
 static public List<Metadata> recursiveParserWrapperExample() throws IOException,
        SAXException, TikaException {
    Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();

    ContentHandlerFactory factory = new BasicContentHandlerFactory(
            BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.HTML, -1);
    RecursiveParserWrapper wrapper = new RecursiveParserWrapper(p);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.set(TikaCoreProperties.ORIGINAL_RESOURCE_NAME, "test.rar");
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    RecursiveParserWrapperHandler handler = new RecursiveParserWrapperHandler(factory, -1);
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\alex\\home\\projects\\self\\zip\\test.rar"))) {
        wrapper.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
    }
    return handler.getMetadataList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and it's so simple just change

```
    ContentHandlerFactory factory = new BasicContentHandlerFactory(
        BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.HTML, -1);
```

to

```
    ContentHandlerFactory factory = new BasicContentHandlerFactory(
        BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.IGNORE, -1);
```

And that's it, now handler will return only metdata from files.